# angular 2 redirect using router.navigate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm new to angular 2 and trying to create a login app which I managed okay however after checking user/pass then redirect to dashboard it reloads the app. Is there a way to not refresh the page using router.navigate?

Edit: it redirects to dashboard first then reloads the page then redirects again back to dashboard.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './app/login/views/login.html',
})

export class LoginComponent {
    constructor(public router: Router) {}
    data = {
        username: "",
        password: "",
    };
    loginAction (){
        if(this.data.username=="user1" && this.data.password=="pass1"){
            console.log('do redirect to dashboard');
            this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        } else {
            console.log('Something is wrong with your user/password.');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);

Comment: yeah did that too and still refresh the page, also this should be a comment than an answer.

Comment: hm perhaps that's the answer. Another question about routing, is there a way to restrict user from doing /dashboard? if they force to go to this route  without checking localStorage it should redirect them back. Normally it'd be something like if(localStorage.getItem)..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `relativeTo`

```
router.navigate(['dashboard'], {relativeTo: route});
```

Comment: not yet however that's giving me an error compilation, tired injecting route in the const and import but in {relativeTo: route} route is can't find name. See my edit in my original post.